# Estar "com dor de" vs estar "com dor na"

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras, diferenças

Qual é a diferença entre ***estar com dor de*** e ***estar com dor na***?

Há dois exemplos:

> Estou com dor **de** garganta!
>
> Estou com dor **n**as costas!

Quando usar ***de*** e quando, ***na***? Eles podem ser substituídos? Pode ser que *dor de* garganta é mais comum e por isso usamos ***de***?

Comment: Ao meu ver, *de garganta* está explicando qual o tipo da dor. Normalmente falamos isso quando queremos dizer: *Estou com a garganta inflamada*. Por outro lado, *dor na garganta*, na minha opinião, é muito amplo. Pode ser caso que a pessoa engoliu e machucou a garganta, pode ser também amidalite, faringite etc. *Dor na cabeça*, por exemplo, me passa a ideia de que pode ser qualquer tipo de dor como uma pancada, por exemplo; *Dor de cabeça* me passa uma ideia de *enxaqueca*.

Comment: Concordo com o @ValdeirPsr, com exceção da última observação, dado que *enxaqueca* é um transtorno que inclui outros sintomas além da dor de cabeça.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A ***"dor de ..."*** é uma entidade clínica. Os seguintes tipos são "dor de" e referem-se a dor decorrente de uma afecção nesses órgãos/partes do corpo humano. É quase como um diagnóstico clínico:

- dor de estômago
- dor de dente
- dor de cabeça
- dor de barriga
- dor de ouvido
- dor de cotovelo (no caso é uma expressão, e não se trata de dor física)
- dor de garganta

Já a ***dor na(s) ou no(s)*** refere-se à localização, mas não necessariamente indica que a causa da dor esteja naquele órgão. Por exemplo, cálculo em vias urinárias pode ocasionar dor nos testículos, embora aqueles órgãos não tenham qualquer acometimento:

- dor na canela
- dor na cabeça
- dor no ouvido
- dor no cotovelo
- dor nos joelhos
- dor nos braços
- dor nas pernas
- dor nas virilhas

Já a "dor em..." refere-se à característica ("caráter", em medicina) da dor.

- dor em pontada
- dor em aperto
- dor em fisgada
- dor em queimação

E ainda temos as "dores do parto" (’decorrentes do parto’).

Comment: Já agora, para completar, pelo menos em Portugal há uma entidade clínica muito bem definida, que é a *dor de corno*. Não sei é se a medicina já arranjou paliativo...

Comment: @Jacinto  Também temos a dor de corno por aqui.  Mas não parece ser epidêmica.  Dizem que para não ter dor de corno, você tem que comer bem e manter sua forma.

Answer (score 5):

Há expressões fixas com significado específico. Alguns exemplos são:

- dor de barriga
- dor de cabeça
- dor de cotovelo

(Os significados podem ser checados num [dicionário](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/dor).)

Fora essas expressões, em geral se deve utilizar "dor em". Por exemplo, não se diz em pt-BR "dor de costas", mas "dor nas costas".

Quando uma expressão existe, não usá-la sugere um significado distinto. Por exemplo (de [Valdeir Psr](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users/2759)): "dor de garganta" via de regra [significa](https://dicionario.priberam.org/dor%20de%20garganta) dor advinda de "inflamação da garganta"; então dizer "dor *na* garganta" sugeriria que a dor tem origem distinta, que não de inflação. 
Similarmente, de acordo com [Artefacto](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users/249), em pt-PT, "uma *dor de costas* será normalmente uma dor na coluna", enquanto uma "dor nas costas" pode se referir à dor de uma queimadura nas costas.

Comment: em pt há dores de costas e dores nas costas. Uma dor nas costas pode não ser uma dor de costas (por exemplo, a dor causada por uma borbulha nas costas, é uma dor nas costas, mas não uma dor de costas). Uma dor de costas será normalmente uma dor na coluna.

Comment: Obrigado, @Artefacto, vou adicionar que esse exemplo é pt-BR.

Answer (score 3):

*Dor **de** qualquer coisa* designa um tipo de *dor*, enquanto *dor **em** qualquer sítio* designa o sítio em que a dor ocorre.

Por exemplo, *dor de barriga* será uma dor nos intestinos, ou talvez no estômago, possivelmente causada por algo que se comeu; uma *dor de costas* uma dor na coluna ou quando muito uma dor muscular nas costas pouco localizada. Se a dor for de outro tipo (uma queimadura na zona do ventre ou nas costas, por exemplo), então será apenas uma dor **nesse** local. Uma *dor **de** x* será sempre uma *dor **em** x*, mas o contrário não é verdade.

Depois, existem expressões como *dor de cotovelo*, *dor de coração*, que têm significados específicos (inveja, desgosto amoroso).

Answer (score 0):

Exemplo: "Dor de cabeça" e "dor na cabeça" vão, provavelmente, indicar duas situações diferentes. O uso do "de" ou "na" vai se adequar melhor dependendo da situação. não há uma regra para definir o que é certo.

Comment: As outras respostas indicam regras. Estão erradas?